# How can std::function accept all function objects with the same function call operator signature?

Tags: c++, std-function, function-object

I am curious as to how `std::function` can accept objects of different types as long as they have the same function call operator signature. For instance, these two structs are clearly unrelated, and yet, the same std::function object can be assigned to both of them.

```
struct A {
    int operator()(int a) {
        return a;
    }
};

struct B {
    int operator()(int a) {
        return a;
    }
};

int main() {
    function<int(int)> f;
    f = B{}; //OK
    f = A{}; //OK
}
```

Could someone explain how is this possible?

Comment: You can try having a first stab at it by reading the source code of the `<functional>` header from your standard library :) -- The general name of the technique is *type erasure*.